# AWS Access keys without accessing the console

Tags: amazon-iam

Is it possible to get AWS access keys without generating one from the console?

I want to be able to create a script that will ask for user/password/(TOTP) and generate temporary access keys in order to perform multiple tasks.
The goal being to be able to give one program to dev so they don't even have to deal with access keys every time since they know their password.

I looked everywhere I believe, but cannot find any resources on if it is even doable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is doable.

Both via Command Line Interface (CLI) and API are possible.

The CLI command is:

```
aws iam create-access-key
```

The API call is:

```
CreateAccessKey
```

See documentation reference below for more information.  It is a good read and covers best practice topics like rotating your keys with API or CLI.  Another good best practice is **NOT** using your root account for everyday use.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html#Using_CreateAccessKey_CLIAPI

**UPDATE KEY ROTATION EXAMPLE USING CLI:**

Before you try this from the CLI - create a new IAM user with Administrator privileges.

**Step 1** - configure the CLI to use the Administrator keys:

```
aws configure
```

then enter the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key for Administrator.

**Step 2** - list the keys for user foo

```
 aws iam list-access-keys --user-name foo
```

The output will be similar to:

```
{
    "AccessKeyMetadata": [
        {
            "UserName": "foo",
            "AccessKeyId": "AKIAIY*****A7YBHCBEBQ",
            "Status": "Active",
            "CreateDate": "2018-11-10T14:02:56Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Verify there is only one, because a user can have maximum of 2.  If they have 2 already, then step 3 will fail.

**Step 3** - create a new key for user foo

```
aws iam create-access-key --user-name foo
```

you will see output similar to below.  This is the only time you will see the secret key for the new set, so you need to preserve it.

```
{
    "AccessKey": {
        "UserName": "foo",
        "AccessKeyId": "****GAGA*****WEFWEWE",
        "Status": "Active",
        "SecretAccessKey": "*****sEcReT*****Tasdasd",
        "CreateDate": "2018-12-01T19:16:41Z"
    }
}
```

You new key is created and active.  Now you need to remove the older key to complete the rotation.  I will leave that step up to you.

If you get the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the ListAccessKeys operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

then this is a sign you are trying this from an account that your token is old, invalid, or doesnt have the correct privileges.

Comment: Sounds good! I thought this also needed access keys for some reason -- to rotate the keys. I will give it a try and report back. Thank you!!

Comment: So it looks like you do need access keys first. The --user parameters is to specify the user you want to get the keys for. Not the user to authenticate as.

An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateAccessKey operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

Comment: are you getting this error when you use CLI?  or API?

Comment: see updated answer for example with steps to follow to get successful key rotation.

Comment: I getting this when I used the cli, from your comment. My goal is to get the access keys without any prior access keys and without going to the console. In order to simplify the workflow.

Comment: Thanks, I did not see those edits as I was writing my answer. I thought aws configure would also be the answers, but it does not ask for a user/password rather access keys which assume the user already got those from somewhere.

Comment: The only way the users will be able to do this is if they also have admin privileges

Comment: OK yeah, that's what I would have thought, well that's fine I have the user going through the console every time. Thank you for your time and your detailed answer!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185376/discussion-between-taterhead-and-tehmoon).